# MongoDB update subdocument changes its _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the next document, and I want to update the addresses with id of 21, change the alias to 'Family'. I run `User.update({ _id: 2, 'addresses._id': 21 }, { 'addresses.$': newAddress });`

Which works fine, with an annoying side effect, is that Mongo generates a new id for the subdocument. Is there any way to update a subdocument without getting a new id?

```
'user': {
  '_id': 2,
  'addresses': [
    {
      '_id': '20',
      'alias': 'Work',
      'postal_code': 1235
    },
    {
      '_id': '21',
      'alias': 'Home',
      'postal_code': 1235
    }
  ]
}
```

I already solved this using

```
User.update(
  { _id: req.user._id, 'addresses._id': addressId },
  { $set: {
    'addresses.$.alias': newAddress.alias,
    'addresses.$.address': newAddress.address,
    'addresses.$.areaId': newAddress.areaId,
    'addresses.$.cityId': newAddress.cityId,
    'addresses.$.postal_code': newAddress.postal_code
  } }
);
```

This doesn't change the id of the subdocument, but I don't like this solution for obvious reasons.

Comment: Subdocument _id's are not `type ObjectIds`,  they're standard `type String`.  Mongo automatically generates a dynamic string id for these subdocs everytime they're created or modified.  You should think about migrating your sub-documents (*Addresses*) to their its own Model if you want static _id's that do not change upon an update.  Then use a Model Reference with the ObjectId type,  on the *User* schema definition.  Then when calling `User.update()`, populate the subdocument content, from its model Reference name *Address* and filter by `_id` to modify the target Address doc.

Comment: @TobiahRex the subdocument _id values are of type ObjectId in my version of Mongoose and MongoDB, so perhaps this has changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding to JasonCust's answer, the correct approach is to inject the old id into the new address to keep the id unchanged and avoid having to enter each individual key.

Below is an example:

```js
  const userSchema = new Schema({
    addresses: [{ country: String }]
  });

  const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
  const user = await User.create({
    addresses: [
      { country: 'Egypt' }
    ]
  });

  const oldAddressId = user.addresses[0]._id;

  //
  const newAddress = {
    _id: oldAddressId,
    country: 'Japan'
  };

  await User.updateOne({ 'addresses._id': oldAddressId }, { 'addresses.$': newAddress });
  const userAfterUpdate = await User.findOne({ _id: user._id });

  assert.equal(userAfterUpdate.addresses[0].country, 'Japan');
  assert.equal(userAfterUpdate.addresses[0]._id.toString(), oldAddressId.toString());
```

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: no. In essence the update object `{ 'addresses.$': newAddress }` is a command to replace the entire object at the matched pointer location with the `newAddress` object. That said, if the `newAddress` object includes the `_id` value then it should be stored as the value.

Comment: Trying to do that gives me an error `MongoError: After applying the update to the document {_id: ObjectId('5a75e2df00e8b63d73406749') , ...}, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: ObjectId('5a7b392f62f7e35af83b8558')`

Comment: Received that error when I did is `newAddress._id = req.params.addressId` and then
`User.update({ _id: 2, 'addresses._id': 21 }, { 'addresses.$': newAddress });`

Comment: Works in Mongoose v5.5.5 and MonboDB 3.0.2